# Why isn't this simple MVC form posting the model back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set up a simple dotnetfiddle but can't get the model to appear in the HttpPost action (thought it is called because I can manually set the vm.Name value if I hardcode it to set a value).

So if you run the fiddle and specify a value in the Name box and click Save, instead of seeing yout name you just typed in reappear, it gets the initial value returned ("Surname").  If you debug this in VS, the model doesn't have it's data set.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRZWNn)

Code for the record:

**Model**

```
public class Parent
{
    public String Name;

    public Parent()
    {
        Name = "Surname";

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class FormsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Forms
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var p = new Parent();
        return View(p);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MobileMvc.Models.Parent vm)
    {
        //vm.Name = "dddd";
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model MobileMvc.Models.Parent

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>



    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-7">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Thanks

ANSWER

Bah! Should have made the fields properties - I wasted hours on this and realise what I've done within 5 minutes of making the post here - sorry!

Comment: Because your model contains only a field - it needs to be a property - `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EZTgTz

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I realised what the problem was almost as soon as I'd posted the question.  A real facepalm moment!